# Location Based Application for iphone

Tags: iphone, core-location

I want to create an application which retrieves the latitude and longitude value of the current position of the iphone, give those values to some 3rd party server and gets details about that place, if possible show a map of that area on an imageview. I've done for the part of getting the locale information, ie to  get the latitude and longitude value. I don't know about the providers those who are serving for the latter part. If anyone knows about this, pls help.

Comment: What kind of details are you looking for? Traffic reports? Nearby bike paths? Restaurants that are nearby? The name of the local sports team? National Landmarks? The state bird? Strip Clubs? Need more info.

Comment: i need to get all of them, i have created application to get the location using core location and loaded the google map. but it shows only a limited details, i came to know that some websites are offering the details about a place if the location is given to them. I need that one. To send the details to them and retrieve the response from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you're working with the 3.0 SDK, this [page](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2009/04/08/iphone-sdk-30-playing-with-map-kit-part-3/) may help you on your way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [CLLocationManager](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) class to retrieve longitude and latitude, then use a [MKMapView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html) to render it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you have the long and lat of the phone from CoreLocation and you want a server to retrieve some information from based on that location.
It's a bit of a broad question but here goes: If you want to build your own geo server, you should look at [SimpleGeo](http://simplegeo.com/). If you want to build something more complex, you are going to have to start building your own server. I would suggest [Django-geo](http://code.google.com/p/django-geo/) or if you have really specialised needs, the [PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/) extensions for Postgres as your foundation.

If you just want to build a simple test app, the [Twitter geo apis](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Geotagging-API-Best-Practices) are a good test bed.